# Animate background color of selected UIPickerView Row in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipickerview

I want to change background color of selected row in UIPickerView with animation. I'm reloading all components when a new row selected and in viewForRow function If current row is selected one, I make Its' background color to red. However, It looks like in bug. First screen shot is what I want to achieve and second one is in my app. Btw, It will be excellent If I can set that red color with animation

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: height, height: height)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    label.text = numbers[row]
    view.addSubview(label)

    view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi/180))
    if pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component) == row {
    label.attributedText =  NSAttributedString(string: numbers[row], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30),NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white])
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    return view
}
```

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach since I couldn't find a smooth way to animate background on selected row. It can be done but not much of an improvement, so give this a try:

[image: Highlighted PickerView]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //...

    /*
     Create a colored `view` that stays bang in the center on top
     of the `pickerView`.
     The `pickerView` will scroll behind it normally and no need
     for animating background color or even reloading
     */
    createHighlightView()
}

func createHighlightView() {
    let highlightView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    highlightView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.2)

    /*
     Now lets programmatically add constraints
     */
    highlightView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pickerView.addSubview(highlightView)

    //HightLight View's width
    highlightView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: highlightView,
                                                   attribute: .width,
                                                   relatedBy: .equal,
                                                   toItem: nil,
                                                   attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                                   multiplier: 1,
                                                   constant: width))

    //HightLight View's height
    highlightView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: highlightView,
                                                   attribute: .height,
                                                   relatedBy: .equal,
                                                   toItem: nil,
                                                   attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                                   multiplier: 1,
                                                   constant: height))

    //HightLight View should be bang center-aligned with pickerView
    pickerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: highlightView,
                                                attribute: .centerX,
                                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                                toItem: pickerView,
                                                attribute: .centerX,
                                                multiplier: 1,
                                                constant: 0))
    pickerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: highlightView,
                                                attribute: .centerY,
                                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                                toItem: pickerView,
                                                attribute: .centerY,
                                                multiplier: 1,
                                                constant: 0))
}
```

---

And now your delegates can be simply:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    //no need to reload
    //do whatever else you want
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    /*
     Just return a `UILabel`. No need to put it in a `UIView`.
     Nothing special either, just slap text into it
     */

    var label = view as? UILabel

    if label == nil {
        label = UILabel()

        //All the rest are safe force unwraps so chill tf out
        label!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: height, height: height)
        label!.textAlignment = .center
        label!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)

        label!.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi/180))
    }

    label!.text = arrDatasource[row]

    return label!
}
```

Comment: I got the point. But In this solution, I can't set a background color to pickerview I guess? It override the view, right?

Comment: @EmreÖnder :) but if you have a specific design let me know and I will see if I can get you something

Comment: I'm trying to code exaclty this design; https://i.stack.imgur.com/feVei.png

Comment: I found a library; https://github.com/AvanzaBank/AZAPicker I think I can achive it with this library. Of course, It will be great If I can learn how :)

Comment: @EmreÖnder Looking at the code of `AZAPicker`, it's a `UIScrollView` and `UIStackView` with a masked view in the center. But yeah, it's flat as per your design and not curved like the default `UIPickerView`. Go with it. Fork it and modify the mask for your purposes.